# ViewModel has no zero argument constructor error caused by ViewModelFactory keeps being null (not 100% sure)

Tags: java, android, dagger-2, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

So far I followed Android developers guide to Architecture Components and of course, the problem was that their examples could not work with default Factory cause of '**no zero argument exception**'. I followed some logic on Google examples repo, as well as a rather good amount of StackOverflow suggested answers, and blogs & tutorials. But I still get the same error.

Now, *I think I have tracked down a problem*, and it seems to be that my ViewModelFactory keeps being null so that ViewModelProvider replaces it with a default Factory which of course expects a zero argument constructor. But I am still clueless about what is wrong with the code exactly.

So I basically have a ViewModelFactory

```
public class ViewModelFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    private final Map<Class<? extends CustomViewModel>, Provider<CustomViewModel>> viewModels;

    @Inject
    public ViewModelFactory(Map<Class<? extends CustomViewModel>, Provider<CustomViewModel>> viewModels) {
        this.viewModels = viewModels;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {

        Provider<? extends CustomViewModel> viewModelProvider = viewModels.get(modelClass);

        if (viewModelProvider == null) {

            for (Map.Entry<Class<? extends CustomViewModel>, Provider<CustomViewModel>> entry : viewModels.entrySet()) {

                if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(entry.getKey())) {

                    viewModelProvider = entry.getValue();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (viewModelProvider == null) {

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class " + modelClass);
        }

        try {

            return (T) viewModelProvider.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And AppComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class, ViewModelModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(App application);
        AppComponent build();
    }
    void inject(App application);
}
```

And then ViewModelModule

```
@Module
public abstract class ViewModelModule {

    @Binds
    abstract ViewModelProvider.Factory bindViewModelFactory(ViewModelFactory viewModelFactory);

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(HourlyViewModel.class)
    abstract ViewModel bindHourlyViewModel(HourlyViewModel hourlyViewModel);
}
```

And a ViewModelKey

```
@Documented
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
@interface ViewModelKey {

    Class<? extends CustomViewModel> value();
}
```

And a ViewModel

```
public class HourlyViewModel extends CustomViewModel {

    private LiveData<HourlyData> hourlyData;
    private MainRepository mainRepo;

    @Inject
    public HourlyViewModel(HourlyRepository mainRepo) {

        this.mainRepo = mainRepo;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(int id, long start, long stop) {
        super.init(id, start, stop);

        // some logic
    }
}
```

And a bonus CustomViewModel

```
public class CustomViewModel extends ViewModel {

    public OpenDataApi api;

    public int id;
    public long start;
    public long stop;

    /**
     *
     * @param id
     * @param start
     * @param stop
     */
    public void init(int id, long start, long stop) {

        api = OpenDataApi.getRetrofitInstance().create(OpenDataApi.class);
        this.id = id;
        this.start = start;
        this.stop = stop;
    }
}
```

My Application

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        DaggerAppComponent
                .builder()
                .application(this)
                .build()
                .inject(this);

        AndroidThreeTen.init(this);
    }
}
```

And how I try to call the ViewModel in Fragment

```
public class FragmentHourly extends Fragment {

    @Inject
    ViewModelFactory viewModelFactory;

    private HourlyViewModel viewModel;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(HourlyViewModel.class);
    }
}
```

What exactly am I missing here? Is my implementation wrong, or is it something missing?

Cheers and thanks for the help

Comment: I don't see anywhere injection of your `HourlyRepository` in to your `HourlyViewModel`, which in case is your exception. I.e. right now `HourlyViewModel` requires `HourlyRepository` to be injected from constructor while your `ViewModelFactory` is not initializing such kind of ViewModel for you.

Comment: @JeelVankhede no that is not the issue, the repo is there and injected, it is fine, I just didn't think it was important at all. I think I have figured out the problem and am working on a solution. There were quite a few things missing actually. Mainly the injection itself in Activity and Fragment. And I will post the answer as soon as I finish the edits and test

Answer (score 2):

I also faced similar blocker, today and mistake was following code missed in fragment:

`

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
      AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this);
      super.onAttach(context);
}
```

`